# Dealing with std::List in std::Map for operator==,operator!= etc

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand Directed Graph implementation (without Boost library that is mentioned alot),just trying to learn things in c++. Here is what I came up with reading various pointers on different questions. I figured I could use a map to look up certain places within the graph and a list to hold the links together.

So the key would be say the first one to be added to the list and those that it links to would be the value held as a list

This gives

*key* John
*value* list
*list* Taylor->Larry->Sarah

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <list>

class Graph {
    public:
        typedef std::map <std::string, std::list<std::string> > MapType;
        MapType am; // adjacency map

        Graph() {
        }

        void addVertex(std::string s) {
            if(!am[s]){ // Trying to check if the key has been defined before
            std::list<std::string> l;
            am[s]=l;
            }       
        }

        void addEdge(std::string s1, std::string s2) {
            addVertex(s1);
            addVertex(s2);
            am[s1].push_back(s2);
        }

};


int main (int argc, char *argv[] ){
    Graph *people;
    people = new Graph();
    people->addVertex("John");
    people->addEdge("John","Taylor");

}
```

What is the proper way to check whether a key in a map has been defined before for a list as the value?
I know that for

```
std::map <std::string, int >
```

the default for unassigned keys is 0 so I would just use `!am[s]` to check is string s is defined.

For a list it starts off with an error saying there is no match for the operator, which I assume it is talking about the List I am using as the values.

I tried using `if(am[s].empty()){` but I don't think that gets what I am looking for.

Comment: You probably want to use `vector` or `deque` instead of `list` for this.

Comment: Err.. actually you probably want to use a `multimap`, as given in @James' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test whether a key exists in a map, you should use the member function `find()`.  When you use `operator[]` like you describe, you end up inserting elements into the map that shouldn't be in the map (it's effectively garbage data, right?)

The `find()` member function returns an iterator to the element with the key you give it.  If no element with that key exists, it returns the end iterator (which you can get by calling the `end()` member function. you use the member function `find()`.

On a different note, consider using `std::multimap<std::string, std::string>` instead of your `std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string> >`.

Comment: @Billy:  Haven't seen you around here recently.  Slacker.  :-)

Comment: [I am innocent. I blame others. I have subtly indicated the "others" to which I refer...](http://case.edu)

Comment: ok I got it working with the find() function. Thanks. Yeah I was told that as well but I rather make it this way understand it and then try again with the multimap afterwards. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map<k, v>::find(const k&)` is the method you are looking for. It will return an iterator to the current map entry if the the item looked for is found in the map, or the same iterator as `std::map<k, v>::end()` if the item is not found in the map.